# How can I aggregate one column in one table after applying a filter based on a column in another table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to do something in Power BI which is trivial in SQL. If I have two tables like this.

**Table Accounts**

| Account | Closing |
| --- | --- |
| A | 01-01-2021 |
| B | 01-02-2021 |

**Table Payments**

| Account | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01-01-2020 | 10 |
| A | 01-03-2021 | 20 |
| A | 01-04-2021 | 30 |
| B | 01-01-2005 | 10 |
| B | 01-03-2021 | 20 |
| B | 01-04-2021 | 30 |

I would like to create a measure that aggregates the transactions of the accounts if they happened after the closing. In SQL it would be like this

```
select a.account, sum(b.amount) 
from 
accounts a inner join 
payments b on a.account = b.account
where 
   b.date > a.closing
group 
   by a.account
```

In Power BI, I can easily build the aggregate without the where clause just by creating a measure in account with value SUM(Payments[Amount]). I tried to add the filter command in the sum, but Accounts[Closing] does not show as an available column when I write the filter.

I already spent quite some time looking for solutions and I didn't find anything satisfactory. Of course I can solve this by doing the aggregation at SQL level but there are other things that wouldn't work very well in my original model.

Thanks very much in advance and kind regards

Comment: In power bi, do your tables are related using account column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your both tables are properly related using **Account** column, you can use this below Measure for your purpose-

```
total = 
CALCULATE(
    sum(Payments[Amount]),
    FILTER(
        Payments,
        Payments[Date] > MIN(Accounts[Closing])
    )
)
```

Output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: It looks like a very elegant solution. I tried but it doesn't apply any filtering. The results are as if I didn't have the filter statement

Comment: I think it is applying the MIN to the whole column, not by account

Comment: As I said, this should work if your tables are correctly connected. This result I generated here for your sample data in real.

Comment: The tables are correctly connected. Unfortunately the MIN returns the minimum of the whole table. In this case it works by chance. If you change the closing of B from 01-02-2021 to 01-03-2021 you would still get the same result, when it now should be 30 for B (not 50)

Comment: Let me check the case

Comment: Changing the closing of B from 01-02-2021 to 01-03-2021 I am getting sum is 30 for B as you are expecting.

Comment: I marked your answer as good. I tested with the case in this posting and its OK. There has to be something wrong in my other model. Thanks a lot

Comment: @edd nice to see it helped and thanks for accepting the answer. you can also give me an up vote :)